# How do I add tags to HTML web pages and sort them with a filter?

Tags: html, filter, tags

I need to add tags to my HTML web pages and be able to add a tag filter to my search bar. Anyone know how?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  I'm afraid your question is too broad and unclear to be meaningfully answered here.  You are encouraged to narrow down the problem to something more specific.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.